# How to Prefix this Input element, using CSS

Tags: css

I have a form element generated by Zend Form as follows:

```
<dd id="website-element">
    <input type="text" class="pre-http" value="bigshop.com.au" id="website" name="website">
</dd>
```

Is there any way I can precede the input element with the text 'http://', using CSS?  (I want the user to enter the web site without the leading 'http://').

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

Use [:before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3a%3abefore) pseudo element

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5qM7J/)

```
#website-element:before
{
content:"http://";
}
```

> :before creates a pseudo-element that is the first child of the element matched. Often used to add cosmetic content to an element, by using the content property. This element is inline by default.

So it needs to be on the parent of the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Depends: are you wanting the input value to be prefixed with `http://` on submission? If so, you'll have to use Javascript for this one.

Otherwise, you could probably use something like this:

```
.pre-http:before {
    content:"http://";
    /* any other styles you'd like to apply to the text */
}
```